# Facebook ask to authorize already authorized user

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I have an issue in Facebook app authentication process, my Facebook account already authorize the app, but some times when I run the app on the device it opens the Facebook app and the dialog said "You have already authorized this app", and this happen multiple times at same device using the same Facebook account.

Also I am saving all the needed data in the `NSUserDefaults` when I allocate the `Facebook` class object:

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appID andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([userDefault objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [userDefault objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"])
{
    facebook.accessToken = [userDefault objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [userDefault objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
```

also in `fbDidLogin` and `fbDidExtendToken` `FBSessionDelegate` methods:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
NSLog(@"fbDidLogin");
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
}
- (void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt 
{
NSLog(@"token extended");
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:expiresAt forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize]; 
}
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: is it after you delete the app from the device?

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug in an older version of the Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/330868496993650/), but has been resolved now.

[Download the latest version of the iOS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/ios/), and you'll get rid of it.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest (3.1) version of Facebook SDK & this behaviour still happens.

Comment: Same Problem over here. Any solutions ?

Comment: If it's still a problem, I'd recommend you reopen the bug and poke Facebook with a stick until they fix it. :)